# How do I get rid of the “Cart Summary” heading on woocommerce_cart?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I'm setting up a shop page, using WooCommerce and Elementor. I started the whole layout from scratch (without using the theme's design) and now I face the following problem:
Trying to layout and design the cart page, I use the shortcode element and insert [woocommerce_cart]. For some reason, it adds the phrase "Cart Summary" on top of the cart overview, which I would like to remove. CSS Hero tells me that the heading is an Elementor element, to be exact ".elementor-kit-1981 h2". I will provide a screenshot.
My question is: how can I remove the heading at the top of the shortcode?

If you need any more information, please let me know.

Thanks a whole lot in advance!

[The cart overview, problematic area marked red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fKUU.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove that heading by adding this to your customizer CSS

```
.elementor-kit-1981 h2{display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of CSS. Use inspect of your browser and then set `display:none` for that part